# Ionic 2 InAppBrowser hides accessory bar by default

Tags: mobile, ionic-framework, ionic2, inappbrowser

I made my very first iOS app, but I'm having a problem with the keyboard.
There is no way you can hide the keyboard. The accessorybar (with close/previous/next arrow) is not visible.

And another problem is that it does not close automatically after login. So the user ends up with a keyboard all over his screen. It only closes when you navigate inside the site.

the code is quite easy though, the app opens up the InAppBrowser and loads up a site where you need to login.

[Login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kydAC.jpg)

[After login](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9JgEy.png)

Code sample:

```
import {Component, ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {ionicBootstrap, Platform, MenuController, Nav} from 'ionic-angular';
import {StatusBar} from 'ionic-native';
import {HelloIonicPage} from './pages/hello-ionic/hello-ionic';
import {ListPage} from './pages/list/list';
import {InfoPage} from './pages/info/info';
import {InAppBrowser} from 'ionic-native';
import {Splashscreen} from 'ionic-native';
import {Keyboard} from 'ionic-native';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/app.html'
})
class MyApp {
  @ViewChild(Nav) nav: Nav;

  // make HelloIonicPage the root (or first) page
  rootPage: any = HelloIonicPage;
  pages: Array<{title: string, component: any}>;
  inAppBrowserRef;

  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private menu: MenuController
  ) {
    document.addEventListener('resume', () => {
        console.log("App has been resumed, reopen InAppBrowser url");
        this.openInAppBrowser();
    });
    this.initializeApp();

    // set our app's pages
    this.pages = [
      { title: 'Launch', component: HelloIonicPage },
      { title: 'Info', component: InfoPage }, 
    ];
  }

  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
      // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
      StatusBar.styleDefault();
      //Show previous/next/done button on keyboard
      this.openInAppBrowser();
    });
  }

  openInAppBrowser() {
    //Directly load website
    this.inAppBrowserRef = InAppBrowser.open("http://ws001.domeassistance.be:50001/", "_blank", "location=no,fullscreen=yes,toolbar=no,clearcache=yes,clearsessioncache=yes");
  }
}

ionicBootstrap(MyApp);
```

Any help?

//Another mystery: when debugging with Phonegap on iOS I DO get the accessorybar, but not when i've build it into a real App???

//Edit2: If I set location=yes then the Accessorybar comes up, BUT then i see a nasty url on the bottom of the page which is not what I want off course...

Comment: You can even try it on https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/dome-assistance-app/id1135786020?mt=8

Answer (score 0):

I use _system in place of _blank. Then I have the keyboard top bar with AutoFill and done button.

```
openInAppBrowser() {
     this.inAppBrowserRef=InAppBrowser.open("http://ws001.domeassistance.be:50001/", "_system", "location=no,fullscreen=yes,toolbar=no,clearcache=yes,clearsessioncache=yes");
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately using _system opens up the safari browser. I need to use _blank so the user won't notice he's actually opening a website.